# laravel validation doesnt work for .JPG

Tags: laravel-5, mime-types

In Laravel5 I validate a picture with the following code:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'pic' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png',
    ];
}
```

It works for files with extensions `filename.jpg` and `filename.jpeg` but it doesn't for `filename.JPG`.

However, it doesn't return wrong file extension but a missing file. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure `filename.JPG` is an actual JPG file? If the validation is any good, it will check the file's content as well, perhaps something goes wrong at that point

Comment: It's mime type is "application/octet-stream"

Comment: add form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your `pic` rules:

```php
'pic' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
```

### Explanation

Had this problem and found that when you use `mimes:` rule, you have to specify the extensions you want as valid i. e. you have to add both `jpeg` and `jpg` extension variations.

### Other solutions

- Use `mimetypes:` rule with `image/jpeg` that covers 3 extension variations for the jpeg format: `jpg jpeg jpe`.
- Use `image` rule which covers `jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg` including `jpeg`'s extension variations

More on the `mimes` and `mimetypes` rules: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimetypes

All MIME types:

> A full listing of MIME types and their corresponding extensions may be found at the following location: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types

Answer (score 4):

Try `'pic' => 'required|image'` and make sure your form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.